# iPhone SDK 3.0 beta 4 broken, Internal Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, sdk

**Final Edit: This problem is solved, after I downgraded to SDK for iPhone 2.2, then deleted all the files in the Crash Logs in the Organizer window (then upgrade back to 3.0 beta 4). Apparently there were too many of Crash Logs associated with my iPhone (like 300+). Thanks you guys for insights!**

Original problem: After I update my iPhone SDK to the newest Beta 4 (released April 28th), Xcode completely crashes whenever I open it, leaving me this:

[alt text http://ivzhao.com/temp/sdkbroken.jpg](http://ivzhao.com/temp/sdkbroken.jpg)

Anybody have any idea what this Internal Error, NSCFString out of bounds businesses are? Now I can't even open the Xcode to do some normal, non-iPhone related programming. So frustrating.

My guess is maybe it has something to do with my Device (in the Organizer window). So is there's anyway to delete my iPhone's profile in there (Ivan Zhao's iPhone) so I can start a new one. I try to uninstall/reinstall SDK but my old iPhone's profile remains.

Edit:
I copy pasted the error message in from Console (Application/Utility/Console). Now looks like something wrong with the external editor compatibility (I am using TextMate as my external text editor.) The problem now is that I can't even open Xcode->Preference to set the text editor back to Xcode's defult. Any ideas?

> 03/05/09 9:22:49 PM Xcode[2457] Error
>   loading /Library/InputManagers/Edit in
>   ODBEditor/Edit in
>   ODBEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Edit
>   in ODBEditor: 
>   dlopen(/Library/InputManagers/Edit in
>   ODBEditor/Edit in
>   ODBEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Edit
>   in ODBEditor, 265): no suitable image
>   found.  Did find: 
>   /Library/InputManagers/Edit in
>   ODBEditor/Edit in
>   ODBEditor.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Edit
>   in ODBEditor: GC capability mismatch
>
> 03/05/09 9:22:50 PM Xcode[2457]
>   ODCompletionDictionary (Version
>   4.1.v255) loaded
>
> 03/05/09 9:22:51 PM Xcode[2457] An uncaught exception was
>   raised

Thanks, please help me out; my developing life is in a halt now : (

Comment: Can you verify what version of XCode you have installed?

Comment: it's the one comes with iPhone SDK beta 4, so probably Xcode 3.1 something I believe.

Comment: Your screenshot says the "Stack backtrace has been logged to the console".  Please (1) open XCode and get the shown error then (2) open Console.app in Applications/Utilities and add any messages at the bottom to your post in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing Completion Dictionary, which is a third-party extension that hooks in to Xcode.  One part of it isn't loading, because it's incompatible with the Objective-C Garbage Collection, and I suppose that when the other part loads it tries to use the code that failed to load, and crashes Xcode.

Comment: Solved the problem on my own, but you provided the insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> So is there's anyway to delete my
>   iPhone's profile in there (Ivan Zhao's
>   iPhone) so I can start a new one.

The profiles are in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles.

Comment: tried. nothing helps. 
I think it's something wrong with the DEVICE not the provisioning (even when I unplug my iPhone it still shows up in that Organizer window, for a second before it crashes)

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, the -[NSCFString substringToIndex:] method has been provided with an index that is out-of-bounds. Since it doesn't look like other people are reporting your problem, it could be that there is some string on your system that is shorter than expected (i.e. substringToIndex was given an index that is past the end of the string).

Basically, it looks like it's probably an XCode bug.  Post the stack trace information that it says it printed to the Console and maybe it'll give us a better idea.

[This old post](http://www.scriptsoftware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=2504&p=6594) describes a similar problem with another Cocoa app.  In that case, the problem was internationalization -- and particularly date and time internationalization.  Do you happen to have Region set to something besides United States in the Format tab of the International preference panel in System Preferences?  If so, try setting it to United States to see if anything improves.

If that's not it, the data from Console might be of some help.

Comment: I tried (switching my region from Canada to US), but still the same problem. So frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

When do you get this error?

I updated to beta 4 yesterday and the mail.app crashed whenever I opened it. It would open the first page of one of my accounts, grind for several seconds then crash. When I was out of the mail app the iPhone seemed sluggish. When my iPhone was plugged into the MBP and had XCode running XCode would take up all my processor resources.

I looked at the preferences and discovered a mail account with no info behind it. I deleted it and the mail.app worked as expected. So I suspect that what was happening is that the iPhone was trying to pull from this nil email account over and over again.

So just for grins I'd take a look at your preferences for mail and see if you have a null account in there.

Comment: I got this error since yesterday, May 3rd.

Also, I tried to look into my Mail.app, there's no null account.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow related to this - for me Xcode started to crash when the Organizer was displayed. Seems that it was related to a malformed plist entry inside my iPhone project...
I have documented it here:
http://spielhaus-ftw.com/blog/2010/08/xcode-crash-loop-countbyenumeratingwithstate